# How I can show that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{3^i(x+1)-2^i}{3^i(x+1)-3\cdot2^{i-1}}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, products

How I can show that the following equality is true:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{3^i(x+1)-2^i}{3^i(x+1)-3\cdot2^{i-1}}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n+1\,?$$

Comment: Wolfram (Mathematica) is giving me this result, but I am not able to retrace why this equation holds.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: I used the following commands
p = Product[(3^i*(v + 1) - 2^(i - 1))/(3^i*(v + 1) - 3*2^(i - 1)), {i, 1, n}];
Print[p];
which interestingly result in the above shown equality.

Comment: Induction sounds like a very good idea - thanks I will try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have a telescoping product.

> We obtain for $n\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{3^j(x+1)-2^j}{3^j(x+1)-3\cdot 2^{j-1}}}
> &=\frac{1}{3^n}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{3^j(x+1)-2^j}{3^{j-1}(x+1)-2^{j-1}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3^n}\,\frac{\prod_{j=1}^n \left(3^j(x+1)-2^j\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(3^{j-1}(x+1)-2^{j-1}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3^n}\,\frac{\prod_{j=1}^n \left(3^j(x+1)-2^j\right)}{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(3^{j}(x+1)-2^{j}\right)}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3^n}\,\frac{3^n(x+1)-2^n}{(x+1)-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{3^nx+3^n-2^n}{3^nx}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+\frac{1}{x}-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\frac{1}{x}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $\frac{1}{3^n}$.
- In (2) we shift the index in the product of the denominator by one to start with $j=0$.
- In (3) we use the telescopic property of the product and cancel equal factors in numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thank you very much for this deductive transformation, which (based on telescoping products) is very interesting and helps a lot for understanding such products and their behavior.

Comment: @EldarSultanow: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is helpful.

Comment: @EldarSultanow: Btw, you are heartily invited to accept answers in case you are satisfied with them, indicating that you are not waiting for additional support.

Answer (score 0):

I could prove the equality by induction.
@Marco: Thank you very much for your hint.

I attached the sketch of prove (inductive step). The base case $n=1$ is trivially true.

[Solution based on induction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktwIC.jpg)

Comment: Doing this with MathJax would be a good exercise.